# ServiceStack: IReturn<T> with array type

Tags: .net, serialization, servicestack

I'm using Servicestack in one of my projects and curios about is it possible to specify the array type in the IReturn interface in DTO objects.

For example:

```
public sealed class Search : IReturn<Offer[]> { }
```

But if I use this class as DTO it always fails with a serialization error System.ArgumentException: Value was invalid.

Some additional info from the call stack:
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.nativeGetUninitializedObject(RuntimeType type) 
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type type)

I could use the list class but prefer to use non mutable type like the array type.

Comment: FYI: An array doesn't provide any benefits in serializers. It's exactly the same wire-format in schema-less formats and serializers already need to use a List when deserializing so converting it to an Array just adds overhead.

Comment: I asked because I need to return some times arrays of arrays from service methods. For example List<List<Offer>> looks less clear than Offer[][].